# How to display one models data in another model django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models: 1) SchoolProfile & 2) Content

I want to show content data in schoolprofile, But data should be display as per user foreignkey.

User foreignkey common for both the models.

School Profile Model

```
class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    school_logo=models.FileField(upload_to='media/', blank=True)
    incharge_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    num_of_alu = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    num_of_student = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    num_of_cal_student = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name
```

Content Model

```
class Content(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    show=models.ForeignKey(Show,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sponsor_link=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    added_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_file=models.FileField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish_now = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    schedule_release = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    expiration = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)
    topic = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categorie, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have used Inline but it's show below error:

```
<class 'colorcast_app.admin.SchoolProfileInline'>: (admin.E202) 'colorcast_app.SchoolProfile' has no ForeignKey to 'colorcast_app.SchoolProfile'.
```

My admin.py

```
class SchoolProfileInline(InlineActionsMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = SchoolProfile
    inline_actions = []

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class SchoolProfileAdmin(InlineActionsModelAdminMixin,
                  admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SchoolProfileInline]
    list_display = ('school_name',)

admin.site.register(SchoolProfile, SchoolProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: the error I see is that you can do inline in your User page. because user has a key in both Content and School.

Comment: @Mojtaba yes i can do but i don't want show school profile & content data in user model. I want to show content in school profile model but without adding a new field or ForeignKey.

Comment: I suggest you use admin.StackedInline  to link the two models than using the  InlineActionsMixin, admin.TabularInline. for this would just be flexible in your case !

Answer (score 1):

Using the StackedInline to link two models is straight forward and a much clean practice, so basically this is my solution below:

```
class ContentInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Content

@admin.register(SchoolProfile)
class SchoolProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('school_name',)
    inlines = [ContentInlineAdmin]
```

Comment: Tried your solution but this one only working if i have to define foreign key in content model.